# What kind of material is "hot-cure resin"?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials

What is "hot-cure resin"? Is it the resin that has been once melted and solidified again?

It is used talking about the big glassy boxes shown in [this](http://www.artandsciencejournal.com/post/44699915623/sense-by-annie-cattrell-the-five-senses-become) image. Here is the context:

> Working with neuroscientists Steve Smith and Mark Lythgoe, Cattrell
>   captured fMRI digital data relayed while subjects were caught in the
>   act of looking and listening, and then used RP to transform these
>   isolated processes into computerised virtual models. Out of these she
>   made waxy resin sculptures, embedding them in solid square
>   ‘brain-boxes’ made of transparent hot-cure resin.

Comment: Hello @user3091, could you add a bit more information or context to your question? Maybe you could provide a link or an image.

Comment: A common kind of hot-cure compound is [Polymer Clay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymer_clay) - a variant of plasticine that becomes permanently rock-hard after being baked in an oven. I don't know compounds that would be transparent and liquid before hot-curing (that is usually achieved through chemical curing in case of most resins), but it's quite likely there are some such on the market.

Comment: BTW, I'd imagine they used misnomer: many polymers melt in high temperature and cure/solidify when cooling down. So this could have been items dunked in hot molten polymer which then solidified when cooling down (but still hot). This is not how hot-curing works, but I wouldn't be surprised if they used that term in relation to the described process.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a thermosetting polymer resin that cures (reacts to form crosslinks, making it solid) at temperatures above room temperature. Hence "hot-cure." Though, in fairness, I've never heard that term. Curing is a thermally activated phenomenon, and, barring limiting kinetic effects, proceeds exponentially faster with linear increases in temperature. In that sense, all thermosetting resins are hot-cure.

Also, while resin can be used to refer to a thermoplastic melt, or a thermoset, it almost always refers to the latter. In that case, the resin can't be melted or re-melted once it has cured, because a thermosetting chemical reaction has taken place which can't be reversed by thermal action alone. Curing in the context of resin generally refers to that thermosetting chemical reaction.